# List tables in logical order of dependecies

Tags: postgresql, metadata

Well, I need to list all tables of my postgres database in logical order to delete data without any problems with of foreign keys.

How can I find that kind of information?

Only I need to list tables name. No more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete data then there is the following similar question: [delete data cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129265/cascade-delete-just-once)

If you would like to drop tables then use `drop table x cascade`? [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-depend.html) Using `CASCADE` postgres will automatically drop all dependent objects - tables, views, ...