# How to DELETE a record which has foreign keys - MySQL Java

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
Car ID     Car Name     Part ID      Stock ID 
___________________________________________________
1          Audi          1             1

2          Benz          2             2

3          Corsa 1.3     3             3

4          Corsa 2.0     3             4
```

Now if I want to delete `Corsa 1.3`, it says `Foreign key constraint` Part ID. It can't delete it because of Part ID.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Cascade delete , Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129265/cascade-delete-just-once

Comment: You need to delete the row that depends on "Corsa 1.3" first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a recrod that refers to a foreign key; that's the whole point of them.

What you would need to do is either delete the record the key refers to or remove the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the field that it's complaining to null, after that, the deletion will succeed. In your case before trying to delete corsa 1.3, set it's part id to null, thus removing the reference.

Answer (score 0):

[**Using DELETE CASCADE Option for Foreign Keys**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/)

Answer (score 0):

The constraint is specified when creating the table which dictates how to deal with primary and foreign keys when updating and deleting, you can specify cascade on update and/or delete or not which is the problem your having

```
create table Orgs       (
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (id),
    unique index name_ind (name)
) engine=InnoDB;

create table Households (
    id bigint unsigned,
    Orgid bigint unsigned,
    household varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (id),
    index org_ind (Orgid),
    foreign key (Orgid) references Orgs(id) on update cascade on delete cascade
)  engine=InnoDB;
```