# SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

In a PostgreSQL 9.3 database, if I define tables `a` and `b` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE a(i integer);
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT pkey_a PRIMARY KEY (i);
CREATE TABLE b(j integer);
ALTER TABLE b add CONSTRAINT fkey_ij FOREIGN KEY (j)
      REFERENCES a (i) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
INSERT INTO a(i) VALUES(1);
```

And then do the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
INSERT INTO b(j) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO a(i) VALUES(2);
COMMIT;
```

It produces the error below. Why is `SET CONSTRAINTS` not having the desired effect?

> ```
> ERROR: insert or update on table "b" violates foreign key constraint "fkey_ij"
> SQL state: 23503 Detail: Key (j)=(2) is not present in table "a".
> ```

Comment: An alternate solution for cases where you're e.g. restoring a backup would be to disable triggers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3942258/1157054

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Only **`DEFERRABLE`** constraints can be deferred.

Let me suggest superior alternatives first:

#### 1. `INSERT` in order

Reverse the **sequence of the `INSERT` statements** and nothing needs to be deferred. Simplest and fastest - if at all possible.

#### 2. Single command

Do it in a **single command**. Then still nothing needs to be deferred, as non-deferrable constraints are checked *after each command* and CTEs are considered to be part of single command:

```sql
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO b(j) VALUES(2)
   )
INSERT INTO a(i) VALUES(2);
```

While being at it, you can reuse the values for the first `INSERT`: safer / more convenient for certain multi-row inserts:

```sql
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO b(j) VALUES(3)
   RETURNING j
   )
INSERT INTO a(i)
SELECT j FROM ins1;
```

#### But I need deferred constraints! (Really?)

```
ALTER TABLE b ADD CONSTRAINT fkey_ij FOREIGN KEY (j)
   REFERENCES a (i) MATCH SIMPLE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE;  -- !!!
```

Then your original code works (a bit slower, as deferred constraints add cost).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dc87d949d19f7dee2de587c06cb05c06)*

Related:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)

---

My original answer [quoted the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> Referential actions other than the `NO ACTION` check cannot be deferred,
> even if the constraint is declared deferrable.

But that was misleading as it only applies to "referential actions", i.e. what happens `ON UPDATE` or `ON DELETE` to rows in the referenced table. The case at hand is not one of those - as [@zer0hedge pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680817/set-constraints-all-deferred-not-working-as-expected-in-postgresql-9-3/28681238#comment98506205_28681238).

Answer (score 5):

I agree with others that the right way to do it is in the right order - but there are just times when that is not a feasible option and something easier is needed to get the job done within the time budget.

In case this helps anyone, I made a procedure that will automate adding the deferred option to all FKs so that the

> SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

command will work. Use it only as necessary of course.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    temp_rec RECORD;
    sql_exe TEXT;
BEGIN

sql_exe := $sql$
ALTER TABLE %1$s ALTER CONSTRAINT %2$s DEFERRABLE;
$sql$
;

FOR temp_rec IN 

(select constraint_name, table_name from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY')

LOOP
    EXECUTE format(sql_exe, temp_rec.table_name, temp_rec.constraint_name);
END LOOP;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```