# Chicken-and-egg problem in with foreign keys

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, constraints

How do I create and insert rows to the following table schema in PostgreSQL:

Table: `employee`

```
emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept, emp_manager
```

Table: `department`

```
dept_id, dept_name, dept_manager
```

`emp_manager` is a foreign key to `employee(emp_id)`

`emp_dept` is a foreign key to `department(dept_id)`

`dept_manager` is a foreign key to `employee(emp_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can work like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
  emp_id int PRIMARY KEY
, emp_dept int NOT NULL
, emp_manager int
, emp_name text NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT fk_emp_manager FOREIGN KEY (emp_manager) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
, UNIQUE (emp_dept, emp_id)  -- needed for FK fk_dept_manager
);

CREATE TABLE department (
  dept_id int PRIMARY KEY
, dept_manager int
, dept_name text NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT fk_dept_manager FOREIGN KEY (dept_id, dept_manager) REFERENCES employee(emp_dept, emp_id)
);

ALTER TABLE employee
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_emp_dept
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_dept) REFERENCES department(dept_id);
```

Note how I change `fk_dept_manager` into a multicolumn FK reference to only allow employees of the same department to be department manager. Assuming you want that.

You might also want a `CHECK` constraint in table `employee` to disallow employees from being their own manager:

```
CHECK (emp_manager <> emp_id)
```

#### How to `INSERT`?

As usual. To overcome mutual dependencies, either make FK constraints `DEFERRABLE` and run multiple commands in a single transaction (more expensive) or use a single command with one or more CTEs.

**Example**: to insert a new department and a new employee as its manager at once:

```sql
WITH ins_dept AS (
   INSERT INTO department
          (dept_manager                                         , dept_name)          
   VALUES (nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('employee', 'emp_id')), 'Sales')
   RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO employee
      (emp_id      , emp_dept, emp_manager, emp_name)
SELECT dept_manager, dept_id , NULL, 'Bob'
FROM   ins_dept;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aa3de6b986f475b6dc23fd6257a7dd69)*

Further reading:

- [Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021)
- [SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680817/set-constraints-all-deferred-not-working-as-expected/28681238#28681238)
- [How to deal with mutually dependent inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/how-to-deal-with-mutually-dependent-inserts/24816197#24816197)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do I manage to insert rows to these tables without foreign key constraint violation error?

Comment: @0xFF057DC : did you read the second link?