# How to insert multiple rows into table B, and update table A's null foreign keys with the new IDs?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I've found a million things sounding *kind of* similar on StackOverflow, but not my case exactly. I'll simplify as much as possible:

I have two tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE B (id uuid PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE A (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, b_id uuid REFERENCES b);
```

There are some `NULL` values in `A.b_id`. I am trying to create a migration that does the following:

***For every row in `A` with no `b_id`, create a new row in `B`, and assign its `id` to `A.b_id`.***

How can I accomplish this in one query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a distinct entry in `b` for every row with a missing UUID in `a`:

```sql
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE a
   SET    b_id = gen_random_uuid()
   WHERE  b_id IS NULL
   RETURNING b_id
   )
INSERT INTO b (id)
SELECT b_id FROM upd;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1ea233a7c4da927516cffa3078c1f235)*

This works because it's a **single command**, and the FK reference is only enforced at the end of the command.

See:

- [SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680817/set-constraints-all-deferred-not-working-as-expected/28681238#28681238)
- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)