# How can I create a trigger that will propogate an update to primary key table?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Say I have a table that is has a primary key like:

```
product
-id
-modified_at
```

There are other tables that have the `product_id` as a foreign key:

```
inventory
-id
-product_id

options
-id
-product_id
```

I want to update the `product.modified_at` column every time there is an update to any of the other tables `inventory` and `options`.

Can I use a trigger to do this?

`update product set modified_at=NOW() where id=@product_id`

Comment: Yes, you can do just that. It's `NEW.product_id` though not `@product_id`, assuming you are writing the trigger function using pl/pgsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the record `new` in the trigger function, e.g.

```sql
create or replace function before_update_on_inventory_or_options()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    update product 
    set modified_at = now() 
    where id = new.product_id;
    return new;
end $$;
```

You can use this function in multiple table triggers:

```sql
create trigger before_update_on_inventory
before update on inventory
for each row 
execute function before_update_on_inventory_or_options();

create trigger before_update_on_options
before update on options
for each row 
execute function before_update_on_inventory_or_options();
```

You can define a condition that determines whether the trigger function will actually be executed, e.g.:

```sql
create trigger before_update_on_inventory
before update on public.inventory
for each row 
when (new.product_id is not null)
execute function before_update_on_inventory_or_options();
```

Note: in Postgres 10 or earlier, the syntax was `execute procedure ...`. In versions 11+, `procedure` is deprecated in favor of `function`.

Comment: if I am performing bulk operations on the `options` or `inventory` table, can I tell postgresl to ignore the trigger explicitly somehow?

Comment: Yes. [How do I temporarily disable triggers in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3942258/1995738)

Comment: what is $$ for?

Comment: any reason this is a Before trigger?  could it be and AFTER also or before is better in this scenerio?

Comment: In this particular case, there is no difference between before and after triggers. Postgres `$$` is a special quotation mark, see [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/1995738)

Comment: last comment... what if the trigger is added to a table where product_id is nullable, so I only want the trigger to fire when it is not null?

Comment: Actually, the trigger will work well but you might use the formal `when` clause in the trigger definition (see the updated answer)