# How to efficiently update postgres using a tuple of the PK and a value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, tuples

My SCHEMA is the following and I have ~ 4m existing posts in the DB that I need to update. I am adding an integer which points to a text location.

```
CREATE TABLE app_post (
id integer NOT NULL,
text_location integer,
title character varying(140)
);
```

I want to update existing records with a long (1000-5000) list of tuples that represent (id, text_location):

```
[(1, 123), (2,3), (9, 10)....]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a table storing those tuples, or you have them in a separate file?

Comment: They are being generated on the fly using python, but I could write them to a file and process them from there.

Comment: I think the *most efficent way* to do that would be having those values stored in a separate table (even a temporary one will be alright), and if you create some proper indexes on the `id` columns (if you define them like `id integer PRIMARY KEY` the index is implicit anyways), executing an `UPDATE FROM` query will be very fast. I'm making an answer to show a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating the values on the fly using phyton, you could:

1. Create a buffer containing a single `INSERT` statement
2. Start a transaction
3. Create a temporary table and perform the `INSERT` statement in your buffer
4. Perform an `UPDATE ... FROM`
5. Commit the transaction, discarding the temporary table.

The `UPDATE` statement will look like this (assuming there is a table `new_values` containing those new values you need to update):

```
UPDATE app_post AS a SET text_location = n.text_location 
    FROM new_values AS n WHERE a.id = n.id
```

Don't forget to define the columns `id` as **PRIMARY KEY** or create an index on them.

---

**EDIT** : Since you are experiencing very slow performance, another workaround could be to recreate the whole table. The following idea assumes you don't have any `FOREIGN KEY` constraint applied to `app_post` table, as you have shown in your initial post.

```
-- Begin the Transaction
BEGIN;

-- Create a temporary table to hold the new values
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_update_values (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    text_location integer
) ON COMMIT DROP;

-- Populate it
INSERT INTO temp_update_values (id, text_location) VALUES (1, 123), (2, 456) /* ... #5000 total */ ;

-- Create a temporary table merging the existing "app_post" and "temp_update_values"
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_new_app_post ON COMMIT DROP AS 
    SELECT a.id, COALESCE(n.text_location, a.text_location) AS text_location, a.title 
    FROM app_post AS a LEFT JOIN temp_update_values AS n ON a.id = n.id;

-- Empty the existing "app_post"
TRUNCATE TABLE app_post;

-- Repopulate "app_post" table 
INSERT INTO app_post (id, text_location, title) 
    SELECT id, text_location, title FROM temp_new_app_post;

-- Commit the Transaction
COMMIT;
```

If there are any `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, you should take care of them, dropping them before TRUNCATING the `app_post` table, and re-creating them after it's been repopulated.

Comment: Thanks! do I need to use Begin to start the transaction?

Comment: Maybe this is just slow whatever way I do it, but to run the update from new_values to app_post is taking 188seconds (and I have 4M posts to run through, so looking at almost a week). I ran the code above, and here is the explain analyze:
https://code.stypi.com/znlqgrql

Comment: About the transaction, yes, you must use `BEGIN` before the temporary table creation, and `COMMIT` after the update. About the speed, it's definitely too much time. You don't have any triggers on the `app_post` table? The *fastest* way would then be to create a new table, this could be plain easy, or tricky depending on your actual `FOREIGN KEYS`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I actually do have one Foreign key:

Comment: Are there any `FOREIGN KEYS` pointing to the `app_post` table? In this case you have to take care of them, just choose one way among many, here is a discussion about this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139884/how-do-i-disable-referential-integrity-in-postgres-8-2