# Sorting foreign key relations in the order they need to be created in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am writing a tool for university which is supposed to take a MySQL database and copy it into a PostgreSQL database and vice versa.

I have now read all the relevant information about the tables / columns into Java objects and now want to start making my create statements, however I have one slight problem.

If a table references other tables using a foreign key relation, those other tables need to be created prior to the table, otherwise the DBMS will throw an error. So I have to somehow find a way to sort my table objects, either inside my Java code or by using a clever SQL query.

I have tried using their creation order in the original table:

```
USE project;
SELECT create_time, table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'project';
```

[image: Output]

However this outputs the creation time only exact to the second, which doesn't help me if they were all created using a script.

This is how I store my tables:

```java
public Table(String name, Column[] columns, ArrayList<String> primaryKeys, ArrayList<String[]> foreignKeys) {
    this.name = name;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.primaryKeys = primaryKeys;
    this.foreignKeys = foreignKeys;
}
```

The foreign key attribute is an ArrayList of String-Arrays of length 3, containing the column with the foreign key constraint and the table + column referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can create all the tables with their primary keys.

Then, you can use `alter table add constraint` to add foreign key constraints to the tables in any order.

Comment: If I do not find a more elegant solution this will probably be what I do. Thank you

Comment: This approach may also prove much faster.

Comment: I would probably take the approach of this Answer, but, FYI, an alternative is to make the constraint `DEFERRABLE`. See this similar Question, [*How do I disable referential integrity in Postgres 8.2?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139884/642706). See [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) command in Postgres.